# Display a javascript message if more than 5 radio boxes are selected

Tags: javascript, html

I'd like to show a message at the bottom (not a popup) in red or something if more than 5 of these questions are selected. I've tried a few different scripts, but nothing seems to work.

Here's the form:

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <label for="question1">Question 1</label>
  <fieldset id="group1">
    <input type="radio" name="group1">Yes</input>
    <input type="radio" name="group1">No</input>
  </fieldset>
  <label for="question2">Question 2</label>
  <fieldset id="group2">
    <input type="radio" name="group2">Yes</input>
    <input type="radio" name="group2">No</input>
  </fieldset>
  <label for="question3">Question 3</label>
  <fieldset id="group3">
    <input type="radio" name="group3">Yes</input>
    <input type="radio" name="group3">No</input>
  </fieldset>
  <label for="question4">Question 4</label>
  <fieldset id="group4">
    <input type="radio" name="group4">Yes</input>
    <input type="radio" name="group4">No</input>
  </fieldset>
  <label for="question5">Question 5</label>
  <fieldset id="group5">
    <input type="radio" name="group5">Yes</input>
    <input type="radio" name="group5">No</input>
  </fieldset>
  <label for="question6">Questio 6</label>
  <fieldset id="group6">
    <input type="radio" name="group6">Yes</input>
    <input type="radio" name="group6">No</input>
  </fieldset>
```

Comment: Could you please show what scripts you tried? What specifically did not work with these scripts? Were there any errors?

Comment: Marvin, to clarify, I don't think I was using the correct script. I couldn't get any message to appear. it was this:
<script type="text/javascript">

  const radios = document.getElementById("wrapper").querySelectorAll("input[type='radio']:checked");

  const answered = radios.length;

  if(answered >= 5) {
     // get the textnode and add text
     Test
  }
 </script>

but rahuls script below seems to accomplish what I was trying to get it to do. I just need to filter out "no" as an answer so that only yes counts toward the total.

Comment: I understand that the script was not working, but on StackOverflow it is better to share what you have to show that you put in research effort, and the answerers would only need to correct your existing script, rather than creating a brand new one and handing it to you

Comment: Thanks marvin, now I know.

Answer (score 2):

Add `change` event listener on document and count for each checkbox.

```js
let count = 0;
document.addEventListener("change", (e) => {
  if (e.target.checked) {
    if (++count > 5) {
      document.querySelector("#status").style.display = "block";
    }
  }
});
```

```css
#status {
  margin: 15px 0px;
  color: #8B0000;
  font-weight: 600;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
<label for="question1">Do you have extreme fatigue or burned out feeling?</label>
<fieldset id="group1">
<input type="radio" name="group1">Yes</input>
<input type="radio" name="group1">No</input>
</fieldset>
<label for="question2">Do you have trouble sleeping?</label>
<fieldset id="group2">
<input type="radio" name="group2">Yes</input>
<input type="radio" name="group2">No</input>
</fieldset>
<label for="question3">Do you get a “second wind” at night?</label>
<fieldset id="group3">
<input type="radio" name="group3">Yes</input>
<input type="radio" name="group3">No</input>
</fieldset>
<label for="question4">Do you crave sugar and or salt?</label>
<fieldset id="group4">
<input type="radio" name="group4">Yes</input>
<input type="radio" name="group4">No</input>
</fieldset>
<label for="question5">Are you often sick or suffer from allergies?</label>
<fieldset id="group5">
<input type="radio" name="group5">Yes</input>
<input type="radio" name="group5">No</input>
</fieldset>
<label for="question6">Do you have weight gain especially in the waist?</label>
<fieldset id="group6">
<input type="radio" name="group6">Yes</input>
<input type="radio" name="group6">No</input>
</fieldset>
<div id="status">Checked more than 5 checkbox</div>
<div>====footer====<div>
```

Comment: Rahul, thank you. Is there a way to make this conditional to it being "yes" and not no? if they answered yes to 5 or more

Comment: @ACEHOBOJOE, your inputs don't have any way to distinguish "yes" from "no." Maybe add a value to each and check for that when you add to your count.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the following query to count the number of selected radios.

```
const radios = document.getElementById("wrapper").querySelectorAll("input[type='radio']:checked");

const answered = radios.length;

if(answered >= 5) {
   // get the textnode and add text
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I've added that as a text/javascript script at the bottom of the html for testing. 

I can't seem to get it to add text at the bottom

Comment: I can't see the script, or the code in the script that is at the bottom.